# Most Efficient Way to Find Closest Date Between 2 Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a an hourly weather dataset that I imported to pandas dataframe. In this dataframe, I have 2 columns as follow (in addition to other columns):

```
wd = pd.read_csv('hourlyweather.csv')  # wd is short for Weather Data
wd['Date and Time']= wd['Date and Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
wd['Date and Time (int)'] = wd['Date and Time'].astype('int') 
wd['Temperature Celsius'] = wd['Temperature Celsius'].astype('double')
```

I have also another dataset (for hourly Car Accidents) that has different data but similar columns as follow:

```
cd = pd.read_csv('accidents.csv')  # cd is short for Crime Data
cd['Occurred Date Time']= cd['Occurred Date Time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
cd['Occurred Date Time (int)']= cd['Occurred Date Time'].astype('int') 
cd.insert(6,"Temp in Celsius"," ");
```

My objective is to find the weather temperature for each car accidents. Since I do not have the exact hourly temperature, I want to find the closest temperature for each accident from the weather dataset. So, for each accident I want to find the closest date & time from the weather dataset and then get the temperature of that date & time to insert it in the corresponding column in car accidents dataframe

I tried to do it through a FOR LOOP (it works fine) but it is taking a very long time to process. This is because I have more than 1 million car accidents. The following is my FOR LOOP:

```
for i in range((len(cd['Occurred Date Time (int)']))):
    sourceint =cd['Occurred Date Time (int)'][i]
    idx = wd['Date and Time (int)'].sub(sourceint).abs().idxmin()
    cd["Temp in Celsius"][i] = wd['Temperature Celsius'][idx]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this without a FOR LOOP, which can execute faster for this amount of records?

[Here are some demo to the CSV files above](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nk2hTMn5MN2NizUWYkAwBeyDLo-Er1R8)

Comment: Are your csv's already sorted by 'Date and Time'?

Comment: @Gepapado yes the weather(wd) CSV is already sorted.

Comment: @Gepapado the accidents CSV is sorted up to the day but not by the hour.

Comment: Doing a full left join on 'day' for both datasets would be good. Then for each row find the minimum between two times, and later  drop duplicates.

Comment: I can help you more if you provide a demo data frame for the two datasets

Comment: @ParijatBhatt I added a demo. Check my updated post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge the two dataframes using pd.merge_asof. You need to sort your left & right dataframe and remove duplicates.

```
cd['Occurred Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(cd['Occurred Date Time'])
wd['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(wd['Date and Time'])

wd.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Date and Time'], inplace = True)
wd.sort_values(by = ['Date and Time'],inplace=True)
cd.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Occurred Date Time'], inplace = True)
cd.sort_values(by = ['Occurred Date Time'],inplace=True)

df = pd.merge_asof(cd,wd, left_on = 'Occurred Date Time', right_on = 'Date and Time')
```

Comment: The merging is giving me an error: ValueError: Merge keys contain null values on left side

Comment: I tried to remove the null values and there are no null values on the left dataframe

Comment: One issue I had with this and datetime subtraction is that A - B != B - A for timedeltas.  No idea why.  I had to do the merge both ways, filter for the successes in each, and then concat those two dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is not totally understandable, please let me know

```
df_accident['datetime'] = df_accident['datetime'].apply(lambda x:pd.Timestamp(x))
df_accident['year'] = df_accident['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.year)
df_accident['month']= df_accident['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.month)
df_accident['day'] = df_accident['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.day)
df_accident['hour'] = df_accident['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.hour)
df_accident['minute'] = df_accident['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.minute)


df_weather['datetime'] = df_weather['datetime'].apply(lambda x:pd.Timestamp(x))
df_weather['year'] = df_weather'datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.year)
df_weather['month']= df_weather['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.month)
df_weather['day'] = df_weather['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.day)
df_weather['hour'] = df_weather['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.hour)
df_weather['minute'] = df_weather['datetime'].apply(lambda x:x.minute)

columns = ['year','month','day','hour','minute']
joint_dfs_array = []
for i in range(5):
    cols = columns[:5-i]

    joint_df  = df_accident.merge(df_weather,on=cols,how='left')
    joint_dfs_array.append(df_accident[~joint_df[['datetime','location','temp']]])


final_df = joint_dfs_array[0]
for i in range(1,len(joint_dfs_array)):

    final_df = final_df.concat(joint_dfs_array[i],axis=0)
```

final_df is the ans.

Comment: Hi @Parijat . I am unable to understand your answer because of the lambda function you are using. When running the answer on the demo dataset it is giving me a lot of errors.

Comment: This is only supposed to point a direction. The logic is a) to convert the date to timestamps and then extract day, month, year, hour and minute for both data frames.  An incident can have a closest timestamp in weather dataset if it matches totally i.e upto smallest value of time which is minute. If it does not, then it can match untill hour value. If it doesn't even then, it could match until day. So, you start with taking left outer join on year,month,day,hour and minute. Find the ones, for which you find answer and then filter that out. Repeat this process untill you get ans for all